# Golang hex encoding

Tags: go, hex

I'm attempting to recreate a PKCS #5 Padding algorithm I've found written in python.

The main line I'm struggling to recreate is this

```
return data + (chr(pad_count) * pad_count).encode('utf-8')
```

which essentially repeats pad_count (an integer, between 1 and 16), as a char, between 1 and 16 times. I'm having trouble getting a similar result in Go.

For example, pad_count of 11 will return the string

```
\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b
```

The closeset I've come is this:

```
b := make([]byte, 2)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b, uint16(padCount))
fmt.Println("Pad: ", padCount, "Hex: ", hex.EncodeToString(b))
```

which will return:

```
Pad: 11 Hex: 0b00
```

This is pretty close, and obviously I could take a substring, and add the \x myself, but is there a better way to go about this?  Also if I substring, I feel there is no guarantee that would work for all the combinations.

Comment: Are you sure the string is literally `\x0b...`, and not just 11 bytes of the code point 11?  I'm not sure why you're introducing `uint16`'s into this either.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge I looked up how to encode a number to hex, and that code above was the only example I could find (basically int -> []byte -> hex string).  And I'm not sure about your first question, but I know that is what the function returns (as a string) so thats what I'm trying to emulate

Comment: what I'm getting at is that if you print a string in Python, it will show you hex escaped versions of non-printable characters.  You probably don't want a string like `'\', 'x', '0', 'b'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [James Henstridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892355/golang-hex-encoding#comment36784607_23892355) already mentioned the formatting you want (`\x0b...`) is not something that's required but rather python's representation of non-printable characters. See for yourself:

```
>>> chr(3)
'\x03'
```

What you have to do is defined in [RFC2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898):

> [...] where the padding string `PS` consists of `8-(||M|| mod 8)` octets
> each with value `8-(||M|| mod 8)`. The padding string `PS` will
> satisfy one of the following statements:
>
> ```
>     PS = 01, if ||M|| mod 8 = 7 ;
>     PS = 02 02, if ||M|| mod 8 = 6 ;
>     ...
>     PS = 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08, if ||M|| mod 8 = 0.
> ```

This means that you do not need uint16 but uint8 (since an octet has only 8 bits) and you also do not need to format your bytes the way python does. So the only thing you have to do is to use [`bytes.Repeat`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Repeat):

```
bytes.Repeat(paddingChar, paddingCount)
```

Comment: yup, this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
func pad(input []byte, pad_count int) []byte {
    out := make([]byte, len(input) + int(pad_count))
    copy(out, input)
    for i := 0; i < pad_count; i++ {
        out[len(input) + i] = byte(pad_count)
    }
    return out
}
```